# Finding a bad datetime stamp in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, datetime

I'm working with some data in an Oracle 10g database, specifically bulk updating and reading timestamp information. I had to convert from an `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` format to a `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` format because of business requirements. As well, the timestamp is stored as a `VARCHAR` instead of a native datetime due to business requirements.

Unfortunately, now I'm having trouble running select operations on my data.

Specifically, when I run the following select I receive ORA-01861: Literal does not match format string:

```
SELECT datetime_stamp 
  from entrytable 
where 
  to_date(datetime_stamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
  between 
     TO_DATE('11/27/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
     and 
     TO_DATE('12/06/2011 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
  and rownum < 1000
```

I confirmed that the bad argument is to_date(datetime_stamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), but now I have 400k rows of data to parse to try and find the bad row.

Is there any way I can have Oracle return the row that is generating the ORA-01861 error?

I've tried using REGEXP_LIKE to find data that does not fit [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9], but all rows seem to fit that regular expression.

Comment: The function below should do it. However, you'd be far better off storing timestamps / dates in the timestamp / date data types. It'll save you this bother.

Comment: Wish I could Ben... wish I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create function td(s varchar2) return number is
begin
  if to_date(s, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') is not null then return 1; end if;
  return null;
exception
  when others then return 0;
end;
```

and then

```
select datetime_stamp from entrytable where td(datetime_stamp) = 0
```

Comment: Hey Hal - I tried copying and pasting your code in to my Oracle Explorer and got an 'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement; Transaction was rolled back.' that I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. I have full rights, but my oracle console is a little weird - for example, I know it doesn't handle cursors well. Do you think this could be an issue trying to define a function?

Comment: try to use SQL Developer or SQL*Plus to create the function

Comment: +1, `create or replace function` would be better and if it's running in SQL*Plus you'll need a `/` after `end;`.

Comment: Yeah - the command window I was using was messing it up. Thanks a lot Hal, Ben!

Answer (score 1):

> the timestamp is stored as a VARCHAR instead of a native datetime due
>   to business requirements

Wow, a terrible argument for doing this.  No business requirement should force the hand of a database developer to use VARCHAR to store dates.  This has to be from ignorance or laziness from the person who designed this schema.  If you can't define as a date, then its not a date, but a string of numbers and symbols that may or may not confirm to any format at all.  Not to mention the loss of doing any date functions, comparisons, etc.  Not good!!!

Anyway, I would say escalate this issue with project manager or whomever and make it a priority to change to date or timestamp.  If you are trying to convert to_date on the fly, even if you clean up the VARCHAR field, you'll certainly run into this again.

Try to fix it correctly now rather than mess with cleaning up strings.

Comment: The problem is, most of the columns are meant to be generic columns that can be 'defined' to be certain data types by a system administrator. So this datetime_stamp column could actually be an integer value, a string, or anything. I'm working with a product as designed and don't have the ability to alter the schema of the database.

Comment: ahhhh, stop, your killing me...really.  Some "genius" decided this would be best to be "generic", so now u don't know wtf is in there.  After all, the database is just a big stupid dumping ground of "stuff" we call "data".  Ugh.  Sorry, but its still no excuse to make it right moving forward.  Best of luck.

Comment: I think the goal was to create a product that could be customized to specific customers without having to rebuild the schema every time. It makes sense to an extent, but I'm usually an MSSQL guy and Oracle seems to be a lot pickier - especially regarding datestamps.

Comment: So any customer can put anything they want in there...sounds like a good plan.  Why not just store blobs of XML?  Sorry, u got me started...I'll stop now ;)